Writing protobufs to BigQuery using Apache Beam (Dataflow) using Python
As the title says, I am trying to write a protocol buffer message to a BigQuery table, in Python.
Is there an equivalent to Java's writeProtos?
If not, what is the best solution (other than using Java)? This is at massive scale and streaming, hence why I am using Dataflow in the first place. I could convert the Message to a dict before writing, but then I am writing a dict instead of keeping the Message small as a protobuf provides. I could use Java, but I am also managing our team and we want to stay with Python since that is our team's core skill set (myself included).

Just pointing out that this is being discussed here: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/32781

Yeah, that's me.  I wrote this question first because I simply didn't know.  When I realized there was none, I submitted the ticket.  Should I remove this question, do you think?
